# Change Twitter widget height with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to alter the height of the twitter widget (feed embed) height in at certain breakpoints in order to conform to the responsiveness of my site. Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function twitterResize() {
        if($('#twitter-widget-0').length()) {
            $('#twitter-widget-0').each(function() {
                if(jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
                    $(this).height(400);
                }
                if(jQuery(window).width() >= 768 && jQuery(window).width() < 1200) {
                    $(this).height(497);
                }
                if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1200) {
                    $(this).height(516);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    twitterResize();
    $(window).resize(twitterResize);
});
```

This is preventing the widget from loading at all. I have also tried changing the `height=""` HTML attribute to via JS but this prevented it from loading as well. I need this fairly quickly so I'm trying not to resort to the API, as this would probably take me a while.

I appreciate if anyone has a solution to this as I'm completely stuck. If you need any more info, just let me know. Thanks in advance,

Oli.

Edit: I should have said, I also want this to take effect when the user changes the width of the browser, rather than just on page load.

Comment: `$(this)` doesn't refer to what you want to resize, unlesse you define `twitterResize()` as a jquery plugin to apply on `$('#twitter-widget-0')`.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Sorry, I mistyped the code. I've edited it.